# Is Spring Data Jdbc recommended for Oracle 18c?

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

Is Spring Data JDBC v1.1.5 recommended for Oracle Database and Enterprise Applications? Lot of samples around the net based on Open Source RDBMS (H2 or PostgreSQL). We are using Spring Data JDBC in a Spring Boot Microservice Application, facing following problems.

1. Force to write custom converters for `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP`, `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ` and oracle.sql.DATE and `oracle.sql.ROWID` etc..
2. Can't type cast `oracle.sql.ROWID` to `java.lang.Number`
3. `Identity must not be null after save`.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data JDBC is absolutely recommended for Enterprise Applications.

Not so much for use with Oracle. 
Since the necessary resources (database & JDBC driver) weren't available in a form that could be easily used in integration tests on public platforms, Oracle isn't included in regular builds.

Therefore it is likely that one encounters issues when working with Oracle.
Some are already known, for others issues in Jira or even PRs are highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you let me know the known issues with Oracle JDBC drivers? Where can I find the JIRA for these issues?